# Porting from Win16 to Win32 - ASM code block confusion

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to compile some code from the late nineties in Visual Studio 2013. For the most part it's pretty straight forward but there are a small number of ASM blocks I'm not too sure about (I've never done any x86 ASM, only the odd bit of microcontroller specific stuff at uni years ago).

The function below generated compile errors relating to size mismatches, so I changed the ints to short int thinking it was written for 16 bit. That got rid of the size errors but now I have this error relating to the "short int 60h" line:

Error   1   error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'data type'

```
static unsigned int Read_TSR( unsigned short int b_offset )
{
  unsigned short int buffer;
  _asm {
    mov ax,899bh
        mov bx,2
        mov dx,b_offset
        short int 60h
    mov buffer,bx
  }
  return ( buffer );
}
```

So all the short ints above were just ints in the original code.

If I remove short and leave it as just "int 60h" the error disappears, but I worry I'd again be mismatching sizes only now perhaps the compiler isn't complaining for some reason.

Googling the "found data type" error I haven't come across this syntax, which looks very odd to me, just having an int declared as if to do nothing in the middle of the ASM.

Can anyone suggest how this can be safely ported? An explanation of why that int is even there would be read with interest too ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int` in the `_asm` code block is the Intel x86 `INT` (interrupt) instruction - it does not mean a C integer.  Delete the word "short" from in front of it, it's causing a syntax error because "short" there makes no sense to the assembler.

INT 0x60 is primarily reserved for user/vendor use, but has been used for a few other things - see http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/ix/60/.

Is this part of a hardware-level interface?  The name of your function seems to hint that is.  It's possible that this interrupt call was part of a vendor-provided interface to a device, so there probably isn't any equivalent Win32 function.

In any case, you may have several other problems porting to Win32 if hardware-level access is needed from user-mode, which runs at a lower privilege level than things like kernel-mode drivers.

So, although your code should *compile* after removing that `short` from the `_asm` block, in all likelihood the program will immediately crash when it hits that line.

Comment: That's still unlikely to work. The OP needs to find out what that interrupt does on Win16 and find a matching Win32 API function to call.

Comment: It's reserved (update to my answer was x-posted with your comment).  Since OP mentioned working with microcontrollers it's possible that this was part of a vendor-provided interface, so there probably isn't any Win32 equivalent.  In any case, I imagine there will be several other problems porting to Win32 if hardware-level access (`Read_TSR`) is needed from user-mode (CPL3).

Comment: Thanks, it never occurred to me it was an interupt, it should have. Much of what I'm compiling is a large support library, much of which likely won't be used by the main application, so for now just getting it to compile is the aim. Any crashes can be looked at on an individual basis.

Comment: @whoasked: if this is part of a larger support library that has a fair bit of this kind of cruft in it, you might want to consider including `<cstdint>` and using `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc., rather than the more-verbose `unsigned short int`, etc., when you have to deal with interfaces to code like this.  I've updated a few older hardware-level interfaces, and the explicitly sized int types were definitely nice simply for clarity when interfacing  C/C++ and assembly. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

As frasnian says, `int 60h` is a user interrupt, whose meaning depends on `ax` and `bx` in a user-defined way. A brief internet search turned up [this page](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/09/67.html), which suggests that it is used in a program from Agfa called TTSR.exe. But it gives no definition for `bx=0002h`.

TSR in the old days meant "Terminate and Stay Resident". Before Windows became multi-tasking, a program could nevertheless ask to stay resident in memory after exiting. It could then gain control when a particular interrupt was generated -- for instance, by an `int 60h` instruction.

In any case, this is not going to work on 32-bit Windows, so you will somehow have to work out what it's trying to do, and then program it yourself.

Comment: I assumed that TSR in this context meant something like "timer service register" or some such, but I also had a brief flashback to the (not-so) good old days of DOS TSRs :)